# Vanishing theorems involving symmetric powers of Kahler differential

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective variety of dimension $d$ and $\Omega_X$ be its K$\ddot{\text{a}}$hler differential. Given an ample line bundle $L$ on $X$ and a positive number $k\ge 1$, denote by $S^k\Omega_X$ the k-th symmetric power of $\Omega_X$. Is there any result on the vanishing of $H^i(X, S^k\Omega_X\otimes L^{\otimes t})$ for $i>0$ assuming certain lower bound on $t$ in terms of $k, d$, e.g.,  $t\ge k+d$?

It seems to be related to the characterization of the big/nef cones of $\mathbb{P}(\Omega_X)$, the projective tangent bundle. But I know little about them. Are there any references on the cones of projective bundles?

Thank you.

Comment: Your inequality, $t\geq k+d$, fails already for $X=\mathbb{P}^1$ and $L=\mathcal{O}(1)$.

Comment: There are in general not a lot of explicit lower bounds for the vanishing of these things. You might get lucky because these are the symmetric powers of the cotangent bundle if you take a Kahler metric induced by the curvature of $L$ and work out the usual curvature calculations (see Demailly's book, for example), but I wouldn't bet on miracles.

Answer (score 1):

The only result I know is the Kodaira-Nakano Vanishing Theorem for the *exterior* powers $\Omega^p = \bigwedge^p \Omega^1_X$, that can be stated as follows.

> **Theorem (Kodaira-Nakano vanishing)**. Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold of dimension $n$, and let $L$ be an ample divisor on $X$. Then $$H^q(X, \Omega^p_X \otimes L)=0 \quad \textrm{for} \quad p+q > n.$$

A proof can be found in [Griffiths-Harris, *Principles of Algebraic Geometry*], p. 154.

Comment: Thank you, Francesco. I know this result, this makes me thinking why no its counterpart is proposed.

Answer (score 1):

There are many vanishing theorems. See [Manivel - Vanishing theorems for ample vector bundles](http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9603012) and references therein. I didn't think about your problem but I hope you find something useful there.